# Is it possible to copy my selection editor into a layer? (Gimp)

Tags: gimp, layers, selections

I am currently trying to outline a picture of my buddies car, and fill it with a solid color and put it onto a shirt for him. My selection editor has exactly what I want inside of it, but I go to fill the selection and its all fuzzy, but I want a hard outline. I deleted the background within the photo, used select by color and have what I want selected. So is there any way I can directly put whats in my selection editor onto a layer? Or is there a work-around? I've got very little gimp experience so there's probably something i'm completely missing.

Thanks for your time, G.

Answer (score 1):

You get a blurry output because the selection is blurry. Make sure that the "Feather edges" option of the Select-by-color tool is not set. You can also fix it after the fact with `Select->Sharpen` but it would be less accurate.

Note that the "marching ants" do not show the limit of the selection, it's the dividing line between pixels where the selection is greater than 50% and those where it is less.

Answer (score 1):

Selection by color isn't sharp because at the edge the color often changes gradually. You must bite the bullet and draw a path around your shape. It makes as sharp selection as your photo allows. There's plenty of tutorials available like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqUineYZmpA

BTW I have made numerous selections in photos to extract items and remove backgrounds. Only a small part of them has been succesful with color based methods.